# timegm on struct tm: Where year = 70 mon = 1 mday = 1 does not return 0 seconds?

Tags: c

Given the following:

```
struct tm tm;
time_t gps_epoch_to_epoch_diff;

memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
tm.tm_year = 70;
tm.tm_mon = 1;
tm.tm_mday = 1;

gps_epoch_to_epoch_diff = timegm(&tm);
printf("sec = %lus\n", gps_epoch_to_epoch_diff);
```

I would expect the output to be

> sec = 0s

However, I am getting:

> sec = 2678400s

Why?

Comment: `tm_mon` is zero based.

Comment: @tkausl please post that as the answer.

Comment: More here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html

Comment: Nit: `time_t` is not defined to be `unsigned long`.  Could use `printf("sec = %llds\n", (long long) gps_epoch_to_epoch_diff);` for greater portability and avoid a [y2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tm.tm_year = 70;
tm.tm_mon = 1;
tm.tm_mday = 1;
```

You are using `1` as month, which is february, as [tm_mon is zero-based](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/). Use `0` and you should get your desired result.